# Pass multiple arguments to map's func argument

Tags: list, haskell

In python,
  with list comprehension, i can pass multiple arguments to a map function's function argument as,

```
  const = 2 
  def divide(x,y):
    return x/y
  [divide(x, const) for x in [2,4,6,8]]
```

How can i do the same in haskell using map function?

Something like this,

```
func x y = x/y

map (func x 2) [2 4 6 8]
```

I think, it can be done using function currying, but not sure about the correct way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### using sections

you can use a *section* like this:

```
Prelude> let func x y = x / y
Prelude> map (`func` 2) [2,4,6,8]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```

see when you write a function in *backticks* you make it into an operator - then you can plug in values to the left or to the right to (for `x` or `y` here).

If you wanted to substitute for `x` then you could have used *normal* partial application as well:

```
Prelude> map (func 24) [2,4,6,8]
[12.0,6.0,4.0,3.0]
```

which is the same as

```
Prelude> map (24 `func`) [2,4,6,8]
[12.0,6.0,4.0,3.0]
```

### using a lambda

of course if you don't like this at all you can always use lambda's:

```
Prelude> map (\x -> func x 2) [2,4,6,8]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```

### using list-comprehension

or you can do the same as you did in Python (use a list comprehension):

```
Prelude> [ func x 2 | x <- [2,4,6,8] ]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```

ok I think right now I can think of no other (easy) ones ;)

### using partial application with `flip`

`flip` and partial application (I think a bit less readable - but I find it kind of funny ;):

```
Prelude> map (flip f 2) [2,4,6,8]
[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```

### remark / `div`

as you only dealt with `Int`s here you probably would want to use `div` instead of `(/)`:

```
Prelude> map (`div` 2) [2,4,6,8]
[1,2,3,4]
```